# Menu icon doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I have created a nav menu and I want to set everything as a percentage as it should be responsive. It seems like the background image doesn't show the icon maybe because it is a percentage?

[Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/35xgfb9o/)

Here is the direct css with the image class :

```
.account {
    background-image: url('https://jsfiddle.net/35xgfb9o/);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: the URL to your background-image is wrong.

Comment: why do you have '../images/' prepended to a web address in the url. If its an absolute url like 'http://www...' it shouldnt have a folder extension.

Comment: I fixed the url issue thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot quote at the end of url value.

```
background-image: url('../images/http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/retro-tv-icon.jpg');
```

URL probably has to be without `../images`

```
background-image: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/retro-tv-icon.jpg');
```

And the last one problem is that `.icon` has zero height. Background is shown but just in this height (= you see nothing). Add icon height too.

```
.icon {height: 20px}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify a `height` on your .icon element.
You forgot quote on .account class

Like so:

```
.icon {
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/35xgfb9o/14/

```
<li class="icon account">
    <div ><p>My Account</p></div>
</li>
```

You had a couple of issues
from wrong url, 
to leaving out quote at end of url,
to applying your classes to an empty div - if the div is empty it has no dimensions so that the background wont show - you should add your classes to your li elements, or as stated in the answers above add a height to your `.icon` class